# Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 16.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, node-sass

Module Error (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

How to Solve this problem?

Comment: Note: [libsass/node-sass are deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated) - they're not being developed any further.

Answer (score 0):

**How to solve this error**

Run this command -

> > `npm rebuild node-sass`